# How to identify tables with "not logged initially" from catalog in DB2

Tags: logging, db2, ddl

I would like to know how can I identify which tables have the "not logged initially" option from the catalog. I mean, I want to have a query, probably against the catalog (syscat, sysibm schemas) and return the list of tables that are not logged.

This kind of query is very useful, specially in a HADR scenario, where tables with not logged are not replied in the standby server.

The only way I know this is possible is with the [db2look command, where the table structure is retrieved and the "not logged initially"](http://angocadb2.blogspot.com.co/2015/12/how-to-identify-if-table-has-not-logged.html) is visible. But this is a manual and external to DB2 operation. I would like something more database.

Comment: I don't think this would do you much good, because 1) you can activate the NOT LOGGED mode any time and 2) the table does not have to be created with that attribute to activate NOT LOGGED on it.

Comment: To add to @mustaccio's comment: to prevent  this kind of issue you would want to set The `blocknonlogged` database configuration parameter to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

I got bitten by this feature after `takeover hadr`, so I investigated it.

The information is in the PACKED_DESC column in SYSIBM.SYSTABLES. Since this column is probably intended for internal use, the exact position may vary from version to version, but in my DB2 Express-C 10.5.1 on Linux it is SUBSTR(PACKED_DESC,294,1).

I found it by creating two similar tables where only one is 'not logged initially', and compared the records in SYSIBM.SYSTABLES.

Also use the `db2cat` command and look for 'Table not logged'.